# How to do nested query using case

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I would like to do a query in postgres database to get values in following format.
Table data is

```
Name    SEQ          CODE   alert a  alert b    alert c
1001    1564948409  1527643  Yes     No          No
1001    1564948409  642270   Yes     No          No
1003    1565646958  642270   No      Yes         No
1004    1565484758  1359527  Yes     No          No
1004    1565484758  502847   Yes     No          No
```

I have grouped name,seq,alerta,alertb,alertc using case.

```
Select  name,
        count(distinct seq),
        sum(case when alerta='Yes' then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when alertb='Yes' then 1 else 0 end),
        sum(case when alertc='Yes' then 1 else 0 end)   
From    work_itemlist  
group by name 
order by name
```

Now the problem is I am getting alert fields as sum based on items. I would like to get based on distinct documentno.

Now I am getting like

```
Name    seq         alerta        alertb     alert c
1001     1            2             0          0
1003     1            0             1          0
1004     1            2             0          0
```

But I want like

```
Name    seq         alerta        alertb     alert c
1001     1            1            0          0
1003     1            0            1          0
1004     1            1            0          0
```

I have tried in following way

```
Select  name,
        count(distinct seq),
        sum(case when alerta='Yes' then count(distinct seq) else 0 end),
        sum(case when alertb='Yes' then count(distinct seq) else 0 end),
        sum(case when alertc='Yes' then count(distinct seq) else 0 end)   
From    work_itemlist  
Group by name 
Order by name
```

But I got syntax error saying

> aggregate function calls cannot be nested

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, just use `max()` instead of `sum()`:

```
select name, count(distinct seq),
       max(case when alerta = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end),
       max(case when alertb = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end),
       max(case when alertc = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end)
from work_itemlist
group by name
order by name;
```

EDIT:

If you want the distinct seq for each name in each group, then your question is quite unclear.  But that is easily accomplished:

```
select name, count(distinct seq),
       count(distinct case when alerta = 'Yes' then seq end),
       count(distinct case when alertb = 'Yes' then seq end),
       count(distinct case when alertc = 'Yes' then seq end)
from work_itemlist
group by name
order by name;
```

Comment: Nope. You didn't understand my requirement. Sorry. I would like to have distinct documentno based values. Say for example In a order two codes are there and if any one code or all codes has Yes then I should get result as 1 else I should get 0. Currently my query returning 2 instead of 1

Comment: @KathirvelAppusamy..have you tried this at all? this would give you the exact result as needed.

Comment: Yes. It will give but its not I expected. I have attached the above data for sample to understand. Actually I will have many seq number for a name, in that case it will always return 1 it will not return actual distinct seq count. For example if name 1005 having 5 records and among 5 , 3 are distinct then I should get 3 . Your query ll return 1. Its not as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> `Select  name,
>           count(distinct seq),
>           count(DISTINCT case when alerta='Yes' then seq else null end),
>           count(DISTINCT case when alertb='Yes' then seq else null end),
>           count(DISTINCT case when alertc='Yes' then seq else null end)
>   From    work_itemlist
>   Group by name 
>   Order by name`